# Is there commercial UMS(User-Mode Scheduler) Application

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows64, windows-server-2008-x64

I'm looking for commercial software that uses UMS(user-mode scheduling) and already be available in stores. If someone knows such a software I like to know it (software name and link to it).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL server uses UMS, is commercial and is available in stores.

And link: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/default.aspx

Comment: not that ums! I mean user mode scheduler that only windows 7 64bit and windows server 2008 r2 have this functionality!

Comment: you can see this link for more information about UMS:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd627187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx please next time google words you never hear about in your life!

Comment: Microsoft SQL server does use the user-mode scheduler. They are the reason that UMS was built, and that's the UMS I meant. Way to be patronising though

Comment: Yes I know what is user mode scheduler in MSSql but it is diffident from user mode scheduling that used in Win7 and Win Server 2008!

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server uses the Windows UMS functions to create UMS threads on Windows2k8 and above. They were the team at Microsoft that persuaded the NT kernel team to invent UMS. They are *the* canonical answer to your question "is there a commercial piece of software that uses UMS". There is no commercial piece of software that uses UMS that is larger or more well known than MSSql.